# How to get event occuring status in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling

I extend a class having all event handling, I want to run a method in sub class when an event occured in the super class. How to do?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on what you are trying to achieve on which class. Most Swing classes have alternative mechanisms to deal with events then trying to override the methods which handle the raw events (mouseevent, keyevents)

Comment: Thanks @Robin I need to perform something after getting some values from the actionperformed() method triggered by a radiobutton. Superclass deals with the GUI design as well as event handling of that radiobutton in GUI.Now I want to reuse that GUI and need some values that comes after occurence of that event. So I extend that superclass and perform subclass function after occurence of that event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Know what event you are interested in.
2. Find out which method is called in the superclass when that event is triggered.
3. Override it in your subclass, while making sure that the initial function is still called.

Try this:

```
public class SubComponent extends SuperComponent {
    // override actionEvent in SuperComponent
    @Override
    public void actionEvent() {
        super.actionEvent();
        doAdditionalStuff();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from the description I think it is more of a inheritance type of question:

1. create abstract method in super class, call it in super class and implement it in subclass. Of course it takes the necessity to declare super class abstract
2. create interface with one method, let super class implement it. Add empty implementation of method to super class and just override it in the subclass. You can invoke this method in super class, method from subclass will be used if you have instance of subclass